# How to Identify the exact IAM user permissions used by a Programatic access user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

In production I just wanted to give only the required permissions in the policy for IAM user.

Currently I have given S3FullAccess Policy for the IAM user, is there any way to identify which all permissions in that s3 bucket are been utilized by the IAMuser, Do we have any kind of logs that states this? So if I could get those permissions I could create a custom policy for the user with only specific permissions that the user requires.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) logs or a combination of both to identify what the user is accessing from the S3 service. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/logging-with-S3.html) is the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks Your help is much appreciated, will check on this.